# PHP Copy and move to new folder

Tags: php, copy

apologies if this is a repeat of an earlier question but I've had a look at php copy and cant quite find an answer for my needs.

I need some php code that copies a file from one folder (this folder is always constant), and pastes it into a relative folder with a new name, for example

```
$originalfile = Templates/$filename
$newfile = $newpath/$newfilename
```

can someone please give me a start.  Thanks

Comment: Please post the code which you treid, there is your start http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: the example in PHP Manual only uses filename, ie <?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak'; I guess what I am saying is do I include the path within the file name?

Comment: yes, you can add directory path.

Comment: Are you Timothy Green's brother. haha..joking. Please read `copy()` manual and share the code you have tried.

Comment: Thanks that's all I was asking

Comment: Have you *tried* including the path with the file name? Did it work?

Comment: If on-the-fly directory creation is required, you can use the `mkdir()` function.

Comment: Please share code what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Juhana you can use copy () function provided by PHP to copy the files from one directory to another

Full reference can be found here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Ex of what you are looking for

```
$originalfile = 'Templates/'.$filename; //provide absolute path starting from root directory
$newfile = $newpath.'/'.$newfilename;//Note you can also use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant istead of "/"

copy($originalfile, $newfile);
```

However do NOTE to make sure that you are providing absolute path which is always better if it starts from your /var/www/projname/ directory. If you are using windows and xampp then C://xampp/projname (its an example)

That way it should definitely work.